# file won't output properly when input a text file

Tags: c, error-handling

I was trying to test my program, to see if the it would get the path.txt file, and output the first line of separated files and directories strings, however when I run the program nothing appears. It seems like its going through an infinite loop. how can this be solved?

text file: path.txt

```
a/a1.txt
a/a2.txt
a/b/b3.txt
a/b/b4.txt
a/c/c4.txt
a/c/c5.txt
a/c/d/d6.txt
a/c/d/g
a/c/d/h
a/c/e/i/i7.txt
a/c/f/j/k/k8.txt
```

code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyPath{
        char *element;
        struct MyPath *next;
} tMyPath;


int main(void)
{
        FILE *pFile;
        pFile = fopen("path.txt", "r");
        char inputstr[1024];
        tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;

//get the text file, and put it into a string inputstr

    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
            while(!feof(pFile))
            {
                    fgets(inputstr, sizeof(inputstr), pFile);
            }
    fclose(pFile);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Could not open the file.\n");
    }

//using tokens to get each piece of the string
//seperate directories and text files

char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
while (token != NULL)
{
        //print
        printf("%s\n", token);
        //basecase
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyPath{
        char *element;
        struct MyPath *next;
} tMyPath;

int main(void){
    FILE *pFile;
    char inputstr[1024];
    tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
    pFile = fopen("path.txt", "r");

    if (pFile != NULL){
        while(!feof(pFile)){
            fgets(inputstr, sizeof(inputstr), pFile);
            {
                char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
                while (token != NULL){
                    printf("%s\n", token);
                    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(pFile);
    } else{
        printf("Could not open the file.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also,

You are trying to read from file here:

```
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("path.txt", "w");
    char inputstr[1024];
    tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
```

But, I see that you are using "w"(write) option to read from file. It would be more appropriate if you had used

`pFile = fopen("path.txt", "r");`

Comment: By the way, don't you get any errors from doing reading with "w" option?

Answer (score 0):

Turn

```
char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
while (token != NULL)
{
    //print
    printf("%s\n", token);
    //basecase
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    return 0; //HERE!
}

}
```

into

```
char *token = strtok(inputstr, "/");
while (token != NULL)
{
    //print
    printf("%s\n", token);
    //basecase
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
    return 0;
}
```

[More importantly, `fgets` reads one line in at a time, so this code is only reading the first line.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

[I think you want `fgetc`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your fopen, you are using "w" mode which is:

```
   w      Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
```

Modify it to "r" and it should work with the return; placed as @frickskit told you.